British show about a Gym Manager
I want to remember this one British sitcom from the 90's. If I remember it was about a gym manager. I remember there was a lady that had her children in the cupboard and would talk to them. I think she was the gym manager's PA or some sort of assistant. For some reason I think the gym manager looks like Tony Blair.

Sounds like The Brittas Empire that ran from 1991-1997.

Gordon Brittas is the manager of the Whitbury-Newtown Leisure Centre. Despite his ambition and good intentions, everything seems to go wrong when he's around, despite the best efforts of the leisure centre staff and his long-suffering wife, Helen.

Brittas was played by Chris Barrie from Red Dwarf. And the receptionist Carole kept her three kids in the reception drawers. Here's a clip:




Correct, and it was terrible :)

Am I imagining it or does he indeed look like Tony Blair?
